# How to store URL parametes in Cookies with PHP

Tags: php, url, cookies, hyperlink, session-cookies

I have read articles about how cookies works and I am trying to find a solution for my issue!

Issues: When someone clicks on a link,for example(https://example.com/register?id=test),the user will be redirected to the register page considering the example link, but if the user goes through the website the id won't be saved and if the user goes to the home page the link will look like this: https://example.com/home

Question: How can I save data from URL so when a user goes through the website the id or any parameter will stay attached in the URL until the user is registered successfully?

I am using PHP and maybe data should be saved in cookies but I don't know how exactly this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Simply store the $_GET['id'] variable into a PHP cookie thru the `setcookie` function.

So put the following at the top of the `https://example.com/register` page:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$value = $_GET['id'];

setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  
//expire in 1 hour 

}
?>
```

The cookie will be available on other pages as `$_COOKIE["TestCookie"]`

See official documentation for further details:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php